# How to call a "link_to" in Javascript on a onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the rails-'link_to' funcionality in my Javascript (jQuery). In my Javascript I'm waiting for a onclick event and fetch some data via ajax. Afterwards I would like to call a

```
= link_to "Show", @mymodel, :remote => true, :id => "#{some.id}", :format => :js
```

But I cant figure out how to put it in JS.
Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can attach a click event on the anchor tag after it has been created with your RoR code, like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#theid').click(function(){
        //do something here
    });
});
```

Comment: My bad. I didnt ment the "how to call click action". I ment how to call the response afterwards. sry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry but can you be more clear on what you're looking for? What is your link supposed to do and what happens today when you click that is not working?

Comment: Ok. So if I click the link my jQuery will fetch an ajax request on '#theid'. I want the answer (:success) be passed into my _mypartial.js.erb of that action. In it I will render a new div with the Elements of the answer. In my regular RoR I would take the object and pass it via a link_to. But how do i do it via JS?

Comment: @hsalama hi thank you for your question. is there any chance you could elaborate on it because I am facing a similar issue. Over 800 people have viewed this question thus far, it could be a great help to those seeking i think.

Answer (score 0):

[RJS](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) is what you need:

Create a file app/views/mymodel/show.js.erb with your JS code. And then add this code to the show method of your controller:

```
respond_to do |format| 
  format.js
end
```

Comment: Ok in RJS I would take a link_to in my html.erb call a remote: true on it and let it respond to js to render the show.js.erb. But how do i call such functionality from my jQuery without touching my html.erb?